# C++ const problems when member value is changed from pointer to non-pointer

Tags: c++, constants

I have two classes `TestClass` and `OtherClass`, where `TestClass` has a member variable of type `OtherClass` named `m_otherClass`. Note that this is **not** declared to be const.

In the minimal example provided below; when `m_otherClass` is a pointer, then everything compiles and runs fine. If I change this to be a non-pointer, then I get compiler errors (the changes are commented out in the minimal example):

*"Non-const function 'setOtherMember' is called on const object"*

*error: passing 'const OtherClass' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive] m_otherClass.setOtherMember();*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class OtherClass {
public:
    void setOtherMember() {
        m_otherMember = 2;
        std::cout << "Other member is now 2" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int m_otherMember = 0;
};


class TestClass {
public:
    TestClass(): m_otherClass(std::make_unique<OtherClass>())
//  TestClass()
    {}

    void myMethod() const {
        m_otherClass->setOtherMember();
//      m_otherClass.setOtherMember();
    }
private:
        std::unique_ptr<OtherClass> m_otherClass;
//      OtherClass m_otherClass; // If changing to this I get the error!!
};


int main() {
    TestClass testClass;
    testClass.myMethod();
    return 0;
}
```

Is this because `myMethod()` is const (and then promising not to change any member variables), whereas `setOtherMember()` is non-const and is changing `OtherClass`'s member variable, and then  indirectly also the `m_otherClass` object?

But why does this not fail then when `m_otherClass` is a pointer?
And why does the compiler error says that passing 'const OtherClass' as 'this'argument fails, when `m_otherClass` has not been declared to be const?

Comment: `m_otherClass->setOtherMember()` doesn't change the member `m_otherClass`, it just changes the thing that the pointer is pointing to at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put const on a method, all your data members are treated as being const. And that is why you get the error when you have OtherClass as a value, since it turns into a value of `const OtherClass`.

Now when you use a pointer of `OtherClass` you get `const std::unique_ptr<OtherClass>` and the const applies only to the pointer but not to the value it points to.

Answer (score 3):

Const qualified member functions in most cases aren't allowed to change an object's members state. This means, that every member which is not mutable can not be modified in this function body. When dealing with pointers, you just say, that you won't modify a pointer value, not a pointee itself. It is because **constness of a pointer is not propagated on its pointee**.

In the upcoming standards it will be possible to change this behaviour by using [propagate_const](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const).

Answer (score 2):

A simpler example to demonstrate the difference.

```
struct Foo { int m; };

const Foo f = {10}; 
f.m = 20; // Not allowed since modifying f.m modifies f.

struct Bar { int* p; };
int i = 10;
int j = 20;

const Bar b = {&i};

b.p = &j;    // Not allowed since modifying b.p modifies b.

*(b.p) = j;  // Allowed since it does not change b or b.p. It changes the value
             // of what b.p points to.
```

Answer (score 1):

> But why does this not fail then when `m_otherClass` is a pointer?

Because it is const correct to modify an object pointed by a const pointer, as long as it is a pointer to non-const such as in your case.

> And why does the compiler error says that passing 'const OtherClass' as 'this'argument fails, when m_otherClass has not been declared to be const?

`myMethod` is declared const. Therefore `this` is a pointer to const. Therefore the lvalue `this->m_otherClass` is also const regardless of whether the object named by the lvalue is const or not.